# How to echo browser locale in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to echo the current set locale in my html tag using blade:

```
<html lang="{{ $locale }}"></html>
```

I'm new to Laravel 5 and i was wondering how to accomplish this.

Comment: If you want to detect the user's locale, see http://php.net/manual/en/locale.acceptfromhttp.php. Just know that you can't always rely on it.

Comment: do you mean the locale set in your laravel application?

Comment: For now i just want to know the browser locale, but now i think of it would also be handy to know the laravel application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking for locale set in client's browser, you can use `request()->server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE')` to get those.

And if you are asking for locale set within your Laravel application, you can get it like this: `config()->get('locale')`

And if you want to get template name in your Laravel blade, just use like this:

```
// allow $view_name in views
View::composer('*', function ($view) {

    View::share('view_name', $view->getName());

});
```

Comment: Thanks! But what is the best class to put the code? AppServiceProvider -> boot? Or is there a better class in Laravel?

Comment: As per Laravel documentation, you may register view composers by using a separate Service Provider. More details: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers

Answer (score 0):

On top of what @jszobody just said above, you could also make use of javascript and the [jstz package](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect) in order to find their locale. Assuming you have jQuery installed, your code could look like the following

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('html').attr('lang', jstz.determine().locale());
    }
</script>
```